# MathML is not rendered and displayed below the textarea

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax, mathml

I have a page which contains a textarea. The user will input mathML inside it and when the user clicks on the output button, MathML should be rendered and displayed below the textarea. But rendering is not happening. Textarea may contain more than one mathml codes for rendering.

Below is the code I have used.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:/P:/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <h3>MathML Previewer</h3>

        Paste your MathML:<br>
            <textarea id="myMath" style="resize: none; height:250px; width:850px">
        </textarea>

            <button type="button" onclick="myclear()">Reset</button>
            <p>Click the button to get output</p>
            <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Output</button>
            <div id="demo">
            </div>

            </div>
            <script>
                function myFunction() {

                var x = document.getElementById("myMath").value;
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
                }
            </script>
            <script>
                function myclear() {
                var x = document.getElementById("myMath").value =' ';
                //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

                }
            </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you run that page using `file` scheme?

Comment: Yes I have runed but rendering  not happening as i have mentioned.

Comment: What output are you looking for?  When I tested your code it seemed to work fine. From searching around though, only Firefox and Safari have support for rendering MathML properly and that's what I see on my computer testing your code on IE, Firefox and Chrome, only Firefox rendered it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MathJax should not be expected to process the page whenever it has been changed with client-side scripting. To request for such processing, add the following after the code that performs a change, here at the end of function `myFunction`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Typeset();
```

More economically, use code that causes a single element only to be processed:

```
MathJax.Hub.Typeset("demo");
```

See the MathJax documentation, page [Modifying Math on the Page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html).

Comment: for without namespace it is working fine but if I am including namespaces like m: and/or mml: then rendering not happening.

Comment: In order to get the namespaces to be processed properly, you need to declare them in the `<html>` tag.  E.g., `<html xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">`.  If you want to process both `m:` and `mml:`, add both as namsepaces.

Comment: Though I have added the namespace declaration in the <html> tag still rendering not happening.